# Drupal 8 installation setup shows older PHP version than what the server is running

Tags: php, apache, drupal, webserver, drupal-8

When installing Drupal 8, just before database setup, I get a few errors and warnings, but I also see the following:

```
PHP

7.1.14-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

However, doing `php -v` I get:

```
PHP 7.2.2-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Feb  6 2018 16:11:23) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.2-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Clearly, my web server is running **7.2** but Drupal thinks it's **7.1**. This is causing a problem where I have `gd` installed on PHP 7.2, but Drupal doesn't see `gd` installed on PHP 7.1 (because it isn't, at least its `php.ini` file doesn't have the `gd` extension enabled). Same with a few of the other errors and warnings.

How can I get Drupal 8 to recognize the correct PHP version?

Comment: your server may be running several php versions

Comment: When you type `php -v` you are retrieving the CLI version.  The CLI version does not necessarily represent the version the web server is using.  Depending on how you're serving content, you may need to change some config files or it could be as easy as going to cPanel and changing it from there.  Depends on how you've installed Apache/nginx or whatever web server you use.

Comment: I don't have cPanel. I just have Apache and the command line interface. So, by "change some config files", what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured it out:

Runing `sudo a2dismod php7.1` then `sudo a2enmod php7.2` seems to work perfectly (after a restart of Apache).

Answer (score 1):

Try To install using composer

## This method creates a project in web folder and other files outside web folder

```
composer create-project drupal-composer/drupal-project:8.x-dev d8_test_project --stability dev --no-interaction
```

Or

## This method creates a project in a normal folder structure

```
composer create-project drupal/drupal my_site_name 8.*@dev --no-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's about "recognizing" version, but you most likely have 2 different versions, one for console and other for web server. Run phpinfo() and see what PHP version is used by web server.

Comment: Weird, that shows `PHP Version 7.1.14-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`. So, how do I get rid of older versions so that this doesn't happen?